# Obj C UIWebview go button click action

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview, uitextfield

Here I'm loading one uiwebview in coding and show one pdf file successfully. In that pdf file have one **Textfield** and **Go** button. when i click the textfield means the keyboard will open will **go** button in down. Show in screen shot. I need that uiwebveiw that loaded pdf textfield keyboard go button action. help me. thanks advance[image]

Comment: Check this:- http://stackoverflow.com/a/16726585/988169

Comment: say this url..want to know  [request.URL.scheme isEqualToString:@"callback"] what is this.. how to use.. help me?

Comment: @saravanar, that is code to catch the event of the Go button click. The event is passed via a URL scheme, a common technique for passing events from web views to native code on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

```
[textField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyGo];

- (BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField

{

    NSString *urlAddress = textField.text;

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

    NSURLRequest *aRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:aURL];

    [WebView loadRequest:aRequest];

}
```